# How to stop Google document viewer from downloading the files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-3.2, google-document-viewer

I am using Google Document Viewer to display the pdf files. I have given link of pdf file to display and it is displaying properly in firefox browser and chrome is allowing me to download that file without displaying.

I don't want to download it in any browser, just view document.

And is it possible to hide viewer toolbar which contains zooming, downloading and printing options?

When i click on view document it will take me to show.htm where google doc viewer will display the pdf.

```
<%= link_to "View Document", course_path(:course_id => @course.id), :class =>"view_btn" %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://localhost:3000/<%= @document.document.url(:original) %>&embedded=true" style=" height: 1039px; width: 1039px; margin-left: 5px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: *i  don't want to download it in any browser, just view document.* - but what about viewers which do not know how to view? They  generally still only offer to download.

Comment: Google doc viewer is for viewing the files which is working perfect, I mean i don't want to let download facility to users who come to this page, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hide toolbar using CSS. just place some div over it using "z-index" and "position" (relative, absolute).

Comment: why chrome directly download the files and mozilla displays the file when i click on show document link, any idea?